# My Node.js app isn't loading my css files

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, pug

I've browsed through this question and cannot seem to find an answer for my specific situation. My CSS isn't loading, I have tried adding a specific CSS folder within /public/ and am still having issues.

I am using express.

PUG template:

```
block variables
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    link(rel="shortcut icon", href="/favicon.ico")
    meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no")
    meta(name="theme-color", content="#000000")
    title #{title} | WHATABYTE
    link(rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css")
  body
    div#root
      block layout-content
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = express()

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))
app.set("view engine", "pug")
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("index", { title: "Home"})
})

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(`app started on ${port}`)
})
```

My filesystem:

[filesystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG70X.png)

Comment: Have you tried mounting your public dir on a path? e.g. `app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))` and then pointing your stylesheet `href="/public/style.css"`?

Comment: just tried it, unfortunately its still not loading

Comment: Check my answer below. Let's see if it'll work

Comment: @Sokmixtp you style.css is in `public` folder right?

Comment: it seems it is. Now, how are u running the node application? @Sokmixtp

Answer (score -1):

I remade the entire project and it worked. Why? I have no idea. I changed the port to 8000, I'm not sure how this would have made a difference but it did.